# Undefined offset: 0 in foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to find the most liked comment and make it the first. But I ran into the error

> Undefined offset: 0

```
foreach ($clone_questions as $k => $valQuestion) {
    $likesCount = 0;
    $keyElement = 0;
    foreach ($valQuestion['answers'] as $key => $answer) {
        if ($likesCount < $answer['likesCount']) {
            $likesCount = $answer['likesCount'];
            $keyElement = $key;
        }
    }
    $best = $questions[$k]['answers'][$keyElement];
    unset($questions[$k]['answers'][$keyElement]);
    array_unshift($questions[$k]['answers'], $best);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Add a check before unshifting that a better answer has been found

```
foreach ($clone_questions as $k => $valQuestion) {
    $likesCount = 0;
    $keyElement = 0;
    foreach ($valQuestion['answers'] as $key => $answer) {
        if ($likesCount < $answer['likesCount']) {
            $likesCount = $answer['likesCount'];
            $keyElement = $key;
        }
    }
    if($keyElement != 0) {
        $best = $questions[$k]['answers'][$keyElement];
        unset($questions[$k]['answers'][$keyElement]);
        array_unshift($questions[$k]['answers'], $best);
    }
}
```

If no better answer is found, you dont have to unshift anything (and avoid the error).

Answer (score 0):

Probably variables `$clone_questions` and `$questions` contain the same values but different keys. It is probably the effect of data cloning.

The offset 0 is exists in array `$clone_questions` but you are trying to get value from the `$questions`. It would be best to ensure that both arrays contain identical keys.

If you have no influence on creating a copy of the table, then before the code below you need to obtain the correct key in the `$questions` table (e.g. by searching for it based on the value of `$valQuestion`)

```
$best = $questions[$k]['answers'][$keyElement];
unset($questions[$k]['answers'][$keyElement]);
array_unshift($questions[$k]['answers'], $best);
```

Your code at this point should look something like this

```
$questionKey = HERE YOU NEED TO GET THE CORRECT KEY IN $questions ARRAY

$best = $questions[$questionKey]['answers'][$keyElement];
unset($questions[$questionKey]['answers'][$keyElement]);
array_unshift($questions[$questionKey]['answers'], $best);
```